# Click counter implementation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having some problems implementing a click counter in Javascript. I have googled about it but I am not able to figure out the bug in my code.

In the following pen, I am using `guesses` variable as the counter. It seems every time I click on submit, my `guesses` variable gets reset to zero.

[The Number guessing game pen](http://codepen.io/The-Seth/pen/Lkdjqg)

I am also pasting the code snippet here:

```js
//let targetNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
let targetNumber = 6;
var guesses = 0;

function init() {
  var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var guess = document.getElementsByName("number")[0]["value"];
    guesses += 1;
    guess = parseInt(guess);
    check(guess);
  });

}

function check(value) {
  if (guesses < 5) {
    if (value === targetNumber) {
      showWin();
    } else {
      showError();
    }
  } else {
    showLoss();
  }
}

function showWin() {
  var p = document.createElement("P");
  var t = document.createTextNode("You Won!");
  p.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(p);

  //document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = "You Won!";
  document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].style.display = "none";
}

function showError() {
  var p = document.createElement("P");
  var t = document.createTextNode("Incorrect Guess! Try again.");
  p.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}

function showLoss() {
  var p = document.createElement("P");
  var t = document.createTextNode("You Lost!");
  p.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
  document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].style.display = "none";
}

init();
```

```html
<p>Guess a number between 1 and 10</p>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="number">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the form from submitting - you can do this by passing the event back into your function and then using the inbuilt `preventDefault()` function.

See code below - I have added comments to the lines I have changed

```js
//let targetNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
let targetNumber = 6;
var guesses = 0;

function init() {
  var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
  button.addEventListener("click", function(e) { // pass event back here
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action of button - stops form being submitted
    var guess = document.getElementsByName("number")[0]["value"];
    guesses += 1;
    guess = parseInt(guess);
    check(guess);
  });

}

function check(value) {
  if (guesses < 5) {
    if (value === targetNumber) {
      showWin();
    } else {
      showError();
    }
  } else {
    showLoss();
  }
}

function showWin() {
  var p = document.createElement("P");
  var t = document.createTextNode("You Won!");
  p.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(p);

  //document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = "You Won!";
  document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].style.display = "none";
}

function showError() {
  var p = document.createElement("P");
  var t = document.createTextNode("Incorrect Guess! Try again.");
  p.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}

function showLoss() {
  var p = document.createElement("P");
  var t = document.createTextNode("You Lost!");
  p.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
  document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].style.display = "none";
}

init();
```

```html
<p>Guess a number between 1 and 10</p>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="number">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Pete. @HaukurHaf, your answer worked too. I just accepted this answer because it introduced me to a new function with a useful functionality (I'm a beginner).

Answer (score 2):

In your code-pen, the form is being submitted, causing the page to reload. So you are really always starting over, resetting the guesses variable to 0 every time.

The easiest way to prevent that is to add `type="button"` to the `button` element which prevents it from automatically submitting the form.  By default, the button type is "submit" which makes them submit the containing form (if any).